# Wordpress inherit parent customization in child theme

Tags: wordpress, customization, parent-child

I have installed a nice template that has a lot of options for customization, including different areas with different text widgets.
After all the customization, I have create a child theme to tune up some small details but now I find that all this customization is gone in the child theme.
The info is there: if I switch back to the parent theme all the customization is back. How can I load all this info in the child theme without doing all the configuration again?

The text widgets are empty and the images uploaded for the corresponding section have been replaced by the demo ones.
Inside de database, I can see that all this data has been stored inside the wp_options table, with the option name 'theme_mods_'+template name and another record has been created in the DDBB with name 'theme_mods_'+my child theme name
I have tried just copying the content of option_value inside the childs, but it doesn't work.

The content is a serialized array.

Comment: Need more details. It seems you child theme is not a proper child theme. something weird.

Comment: Why? It has all the parent features... The Child has been correctly created by adding the corresponding lines in functions.php and in styles.css, what I'm missing is the contents I have already added to the customizer in the parent

Comment: When I say why I don't doubt that you may need more details, I mean that the child has been correctly setup. What else do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

It seems "Theme options" are not inherited by child theme. I've met the same problem and I saw that in the database there are two fields.

**If the parent theme is using [Options Framework](https://wordpress.org/plugins/options-framework/)**

In the table **`wp_options`**:

```
optionsframework_<parent_theme_name>
```

This field contains a serialized array that configures the *parent* theme.

```
optionsframework_<child_theme_name>
```

This field contains a serialized array that configure the *child* theme.

I made some tests and when the child theme is enabled, the parent configuration is not used.
It's possible either to :

- Copy/paste the content of the parent options into the child options and then use the child options. To do so you just need to copy the content of the field into the other.
- Use the Options Framework in your child theme too and override the [optionsframework_option_name()](https://github.com/devinsays/options-framework-plugin/blob/master/options-check/options.php#L2#L20) function in order to set the 'id' field to the parent theme name. But be careful with this option because the parent's options are used. So when changing back to the parent theme or so, your options could be overwritten.

Also, it'd be needed to copy/paste the `theme_mods_<parent_theme_name>` into the `theme_mods_<child_theme_name>`.